# How to save hashed password and send_mail using django and django restframework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django restframework to build an endpoint and i have Modelserializer to serialize and send email activation token using django's email backend via console.But the serializer saves some part of the fields ignoring hashed password, sending email using send_mail() and also any print or logging statements.and it give me 201 response.Here are the codes
Serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "phone_number",
            "address",
            "zip_code",
            "company_name",
            "gender",
            "birthdate",
            "referral_code",
            "city",
            "district",
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            "is_active",
            "is_staff",
            "is_superuser",
            "is_email_verified",
            "is_address_verified",
            "is_company_verified",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "login_attempts",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/p/users/"
            UID = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            TOKEN = account_activation_token.make_token(user)
            sender_mail = "313delivery@gmail.com"
            mail_subject = "Activation link has been sent to your email id"

            traceback.print_exc()
            print("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr")

            city1 = City.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop("city"))
            district1 = District.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop("district"))

            user = CustomUser(
                first_name=validated_data["first_name"],
                last_name=validated_data["last_name"],
                email=validated_data["email"],
                phone_number=validated_data["phone_number"],
                zip_code=validated_data["zip_code"],
                company_name=validated_data["company_name"],
                gender=validated_data["gender"],
                birthdate=validated_data["birthdate"],
                referral_code=validated_data["referral_code"],
                city=validated_data["city"],
                district=validated_data["district"],
            )
            user.set_password(validated_data["password"])

            # send OTP to user via email

            domain = (BASE_URL + "activate/" + UID + "/" + TOKEN,)
            logger.info("before sending email ------")
            email = send_mail(
                subject=mail_subject,
                message=domain,
                from_email=sender_mail,
                recipient_list=validated_data["email"],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            user.otp = TOKEN
            email.send()
            logger.info("after sending email ------")
            user.save()
            return user
```

View

```
class UserCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

any help please ?

i try every possible combination to make it and actually it works like 80 percent but the 20 percent is also critical for the system.I expect an answer that will let me save hashed password, send email via console and print and log to console or file for debugging purpose

Comment: Try `user.save()` after `set_password`

Answer (score 0):

`UserManager` has two functions to assist in user creation, while using `AbstractBaseUser` you should [set one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). On the other hand `AbstractUser` sets the built-in manager for you. In it most basic form it ensures a hashed password among other things.

Wrap `send_mail` in a try/except block and set the response accordingly to the result, of course you can always generalize if you want to. In this example (the two exceptions are not covering all the cases), a successful response is returned only if the user is created and the email is sent.

serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/p/users/"
        uid = uuid.uuid4()
        token = uuid.uuid4()
        domain = f"{base_url}activate/{uid}/{token}"
        instance = User()

        try:
            is_sent = send_mail(
                "Activation link has been sent to your email id",
                domain,
                "313delivery@gmail.com",
                [validated_data["email"]],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            if is_sent > 0:
                validated_data['otp'] = token
                instance = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
                print(f'email sent to: {instance.email}')
            else:
                print(f'FAILED to send email to: {validated_data["email"]}')
        except SMTPException:
            print(f'FAILED to send email to: {validated_data["email"]}')
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print(f'FAILED to send email to: {validated_data["email"]}')

        return instance
```

views.py

```py
class UserCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            if instance.pk:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(
                    {"error": "Something went wrong."},
                    status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                )

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```